# Dollar sign in front of a variable name or no dollar sign

Tags: jquery

I'm going through Scott Allen's tutorial about ASP.NET MVC. I got to the section where there is some code that uses jQuery.

> ```js
> $(function () {
>     var ajaxFormSubmit = function () {
>         var $form = $(this);
>         var options = {
>             url: $form.attr("action"),
>             type: $form.attr("method"),
>             data: $form.serialize()
>         };
>         $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
>             var $target = $($form.attr("data-otf-target"));
>             var $newHtml = $(data);
>             $target.replaceWith($newHtml);
>             $newHtml.effect("highlight");
>         });
>         return false;
>     };
> ```

I'm trying to understand what's the difference between the variables with or without the dollar signs. For example variable `form` has a dollar sign and the `options` does not and then the variables inside the ajax `done` part also have the dollar signs.

In our system where we use jQuery I haven't seen such code. What is the difference? Is this has something to do with the ASP.NET MVC 4 and/or the new versions of jQuery?

Comment: Using the `$` at the beginning of a variable name is a coding convention to indicate that the variable's value is a jQuery object. It's completely optional, but helpful.

Comment: @Tushar Gupta: Thank you I was just fixing that, you were quicker ;)

Comment: @JasonP: but why there is no dollar sign in front of option object(?) becuase this is an object?

Comment: @Rafal_Koscinski Yes, it's a simple javascript object, not a jQuery object/collection.

Comment: @Rafal_Koscinski Yes, because its a native JS object.

Comment: Its a convention that indicate the type of object. As for me, when I create a string var, i do it like that : `var strName`. That way, i know this variable is a string and that i can use string function like `.replace()`. It is the same thing with jQuery object, it tell you that this var contain a jQuery object and that you can use jQuery function like `attr()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$` has no special meaning in a JavaScript identifier.

There is a *convention* to use a variable name starting with a `$` character to represent a variable that will hold a jQuery object.